# Linux: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, jenkins-pipeline, visual-studio-2019, ubuntu-18.04

I have a sample Ocelot gateway service built using Dotnet Core Web API V3.1. I have build the solution in Windows machine using "dotnet clean and dotnet build" which works fine. I'm trying to do the same in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine through Jenkins which is causing the below issue.

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
     1>Done Building Project "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj" (Clean target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

       "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj" (Clean target) (1) ->
       (ResolvePackageAssets target) ->
         /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018: NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'. [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/GatewaySample_SERVICE/GatewaySample/GatewaySample.csproj]
```

Kindly let me know what am I missing here?

Note: I have another linux machine where I have the same setup (**but Dotnet Core V2.2**) where I could able to build the API through Jenkins.

PS: Below is the content from .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>GatewaySample_SERVICE</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ocelot" Version="14.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: .NET Core 3.x [doesn't use a NuGet Fallback folder](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/4079). Is that build machine offline perhaps? As the answer to the issue explains, you'll have to get it online and restore at least once

Comment: PS: What does your csproj look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavosThank you for your reply. The machine is online. Below is my csproj file. `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>GatewaySample_SERVICE</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Ocelot" Version="14.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
`

Comment: Post this in the question itself

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I created a new webapp project in WSL/Ubuntu 18.04 and `dotnet build` works without issue. Does Jenkins or the build script set any environment variables to a Windows path? Any other NuGet configuration?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I created the project using Visual Studio 2019 with dotnet core v3.1 in Windows environment. Through Jenkins I'm pulling the code from SVN and trying to publish in Ubuntu. I didn't set any environment variables in build events or Jenkins.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I created the same application in Visual Studio 2017 with dotnet Core V2.2 and did the same steps and it succeeded. Is there any other configurations/settings which need to be done to use the latest version?

Comment: I did none of these - just `dotnet new webapp` followed by `dotnet add package Ocelot` and `dotnet add package ...`, followed by `dotnet build`. You don't need extra configuration, the build failes *because* there's some extra configuration in there, that tries to use a FallBack folder that *isn't* used by 3.1

Comment: Does the Jenkins machine have the 3.1 SDK in the first place? The build shouldn't even be trying to use a fallback folder - the 3.1 SDK doesn't use that. What does `dotnet --version` and `dotnet --list-sdks` return?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes that machine has the latest version. dotnet --version returned 3.1.102 and dotnet --list-sdks returned 3.1.102 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

Comment: Just adding that this continues to be an issue with .NET 5.0

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue when moving from Windows environment to WSL environment.
I did not find any reference to the missing directory in project files thus I searched the fallback plugin folder references in the whole project directory hierarchy and found it only in bin/ and obj/ folders.
After deleting all the bin/ and obj/ folders from the projects I was able to build them under WSL.